# Wrong spatial information after resampling 2D spatial data (different origin and resolution) with pyresample in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geospatial, resampling, cartopy

I need to resample regularly gridded (in lon-lat) data to a new grid with lower resolution and different origin. I though I'd use [pyresample](https://pyresample.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Problem: I get an obviously wrong spatial location of my results after resampling.
In the following example, I construct a simple 2D array with some spatial grid (defined in `sourcegrid` which is a `pyresample AreaDefinition` object) and some mask, to resample it to another `targetgrid`. The spatial information is lost somewhere in the process, I can't figure out where... any idea?

```
import numpy as np
from pyresample.geometry import AreaDefinition
from pyresample.kd_tree import resample_nearest
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Source data
lonmin = -10; lonmax = 10.; latmin=40.; latmax=60.; nlon = 300; nlat = 250
lon = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, nlon); lat = np.linspace(latmin, latmax, nlat)
dlon = lon[1] - lon[0]; dlat = lat[1] - lat[0]
lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
sourcedata = np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2d)*100) + np.sin(np.deg2rad(lon2d)*100)

# Introduce a polygon as mask
xpol = [frac*(nlon-1) for frac in (0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0., 0)]
ypol = [frac*(nlat-1) for frac in (0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 1., 1., 0)]
polygon = [xy for xy in zip(xpol, ypol)]
img = Image.new('L', (nlon, nlat), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(img)
xpol = [lon[int(x)] for x in xpol]; ypol = [lat[int(y)] for y in ypol] # translate in lon-lat for plot
sourcedata = np.ma.masked_where(mask, sourcedata)


# Define source and target areas
sourceextent = [lonmin-dlon/2, latmin-dlat/2, lonmax+dlon/2, latmax+dlat/2] # [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
sourceextentforplot = [sourceextent[i] for i in (0,2,1,3)] # [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
targetextent =  [lonmin-dlon/2 + 0.12*(lonmax-lonmin), latmin-dlat/2 + 0.24*(latmax-latmin),
                 lonmin-dlon/2 + 0.78*(lonmax-lonmin), latmin-dlat/2 + 0.91*(latmax-latmin)]
targetextentforplot = [targetextent[i] for i in (0,2,1,3)] 

sourcegrid = AreaDefinition(area_id='Grd1', description='Source Grid', proj_id='proj_id_blabla',
                            projection='EPSG:4326', width=nlon, height=nlat, area_extent=sourceextent)
# Lower resolution, different origin
targetgrid = AreaDefinition(area_id='Grd2', description='Target Grid', proj_id='proj_id_blabla',
                            projection='EPSG:4326', width=123, height=97, area_extent=targetextent)

# Resample sourcedata to newdata
newdata = resample_nearest(sourcegrid, sourcedata, targetgrid, fill_value=None, radius_of_influence=50000)

# Plot
def doplt(ax, data, extent):
    ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', color='gray', alpha=1., linewidth=2.)
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    ax.imshow(data, origin='lower', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=extent)
    ax.plot(xpol, ypol, 'k--', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.plot([targetextentforplot[x] for x in (0, 1, 1, 0, 0)], [targetextentforplot[y] for y in (2, 2, 3, 3, 2)],
            'r--', lw=3, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([-12, 12, 38, 62])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(5,10), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

doplt(ax1, sourcedata, extent=sourceextentforplot)
ax1.set_title('Source data, target area in red')
doplt(ax2, newdata, extent=targetextentforplot)
ax2.set_title('New data, with wrong spatial ref (or plotting?)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: other suggestions to do the resampling operation than `pyresample`, ideally with example, are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you're assuming row 0 is the bottom of the image, but as shown in [this example](https://pyresample.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot.html#getting-a-cartopy-crs), pyresample uses row 0 as the top. I modified your example to tweak the polygon latitudes as well as using `origin='upper'` to plot with `imshow`:

```
import numpy as np
from pyresample.geometry import AreaDefinition
from pyresample.kd_tree import resample_nearest
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Source data
lonmin = -10; lonmax = 10.; latmin=40.; latmax=60.; nlon = 300; nlat = 250
lon = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, nlon); lat = np.linspace(latmin, latmax, nlat)
dlon = lon[1] - lon[0]; dlat = lat[1] - lat[0]
lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
sourcedata = np.hypot(lon2d, lat2d - 50) * (np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2d)*100) + np.sin(np.deg2rad(lon2d)*100))

# Introduce a polygon as mask
xpol = [frac*(nlon-1) for frac in (0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 0., 0)]
ypol = [frac*(nlat-1) for frac in (0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 1., 1., 0)]
polygon = [xy for xy in zip(xpol, ypol)]
img = Image.new('L', (nlon, nlat), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(img).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(img)
xpol = [lon[int(x)] for x in xpol]; ypol = [lat[nlat - 1 - int(y)] for y in ypol] # translate in lon-lat for plot
sourcedata = np.ma.masked_where(mask, sourcedata)


# Define source and target areas
sourceextent = [lonmin-dlon/2, latmin-dlat/2, lonmax+dlon/2, latmax+dlat/2] # [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
sourceextentforplot = [sourceextent[i] for i in (0,2,1,3)] # [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
targetextent =  [lonmin-dlon/2 + 0.12*(lonmax-lonmin), latmin-dlat/2 + 0.24*(latmax-latmin),
                 lonmin-dlon/2 + 0.78*(lonmax-lonmin), latmin-dlat/2 + 0.91*(latmax-latmin)]
targetextentforplot = [targetextent[i] for i in (0,2,1,3)] 

sourcegrid = AreaDefinition(area_id='Grd1', description='Source Grid', proj_id='proj_id_blabla',
                            projection='EPSG:4326', width=nlon, height=nlat, area_extent=sourceextent)
# Lower resolution, different origin
targetgrid = AreaDefinition(area_id='Grd2', description='Target Grid', proj_id='proj_id_blabla',
                            projection='EPSG:4326', width=123, height=97, area_extent=targetextent)

# Resample sourcedata to newdata
newdata = resample_nearest(sourcegrid, sourcedata, targetgrid, fill_value=None, radius_of_influence=50000)

# Plot
def doplt(ax, data, extent):
    ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', color='gray', alpha=1., linewidth=2.)
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    ax.imshow(data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=extent, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 20), origin='upper')
    ax.plot(xpol, ypol, 'k--', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.plot([targetextentforplot[x] for x in (0, 1, 1, 0, 0)], [targetextentforplot[y] for y in (2, 2, 3, 3, 2)],
            'r--', lw=3, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([-12, 12, 38, 62])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(5,10), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

doplt(ax1, sourcedata, extent=sourceextentforplot)
ax1.set_title('Source data, target area in red')
doplt(ax2, newdata, extent=targetextentforplot)
ax2.set_title('New data, with wrong spatial ref (or plotting?)');
```

That gives:

[image: Resulting image]

I found it helpful to use an image with more variation to be able to line it up better with the source data.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that. But pretending the example data are spatial data, the result here would be wrong (spatial info remains lost). So are we supposed in such case to actually shift them over the Lat dimension before doing anything in `pyresample` and then transform them again?! Can you perhaps modify your answer to make it match exactly the spatial info from the question (as if it was a map, here countries would be wrong)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "spatial info remains lost". The only change I made was so that row 0 is the high latitude. That arrangement is exactly how it's done in the original example: https://pyresample.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot.html#getting-a-cartopy-crs It's also what's specified for `ImageDraw`: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#coordinates Really, the problem here was how you calculated latitude from the polygon coordinates (which were in fractions of the image) A fraction of 0 needs to map to `latmax`, not `latmin`.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I was not clearer. I meant that if my original array was actual spatial data, your manipulation implies a "vertical flip" (i.e., to continue covering mostly France as originally instead of North Sea as in your solution), but it's just a flip operation away, at least the `resample` operation works and you spotted the issue - thanks! [In the meantime, I found that using `SwathDefinition` immediately solved the problem...]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using a `SwathDefinition` instead of an `AreaDefinition` (see [doc](https://pyresample.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swath.html#resample-nearest)) solved the problem.

Defining `sourcegrid` and `targetgrid` as follows in the original code gives good results:

```
sourcegrid = SwathDefinition(lons=lon2d, lats=lat2d)
lon2dtarget, lat2dtarget = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(targetextent[0], targetextent[2], 123),
                                       np.linspace(targetextent[1], targetextent[3], 97))
targetgrid = SwathDefinition(lons=lon2dtarget, lats=lat2dtarget)
```

[image]